# Outlook Addin requires admin permissions to launch

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, registry, outlook-addin

i had coded an outlook addin which needs to modify the registry before it can perform the required function. I initially achieved this by having one more project (.exe) which modifies the registry and then launching this process from my outlook addin. Now i want to have this function in my addin itself but in the project properties, there is no option to provide a manual manifest file for running this addin in admin mode and hence when i try modifying the registry, it throws an exception when outlook launches. Can anyone help me out on this.

I am coding in C# and though my first approach was working fine, i am not sure if launching another application from my outlook addin is a nice way to accomplish things.

Thanks
Pawan

Answer (score 0):

Why not install your addin from an installer that sets the appropriate access rights onto that particular registry key?

If your ordinary users has to modify that registry key on *each run* of Outlook, the best thing would be to formalize that right through security settings.

Comment: formalize through security settings ... does that mean that i change the registry value permanently. I am not sure if that's safe to do. The key i am concerned with is "EnableHighSecurityMode" for custom status in communicator

Comment: and yes, my addin has to mess with the registry on every startup. What i am basically trying to do is extract outlook calendar and set the communicator status to the meeting subject rather than just saying "In a meeting". the addin is working but i just want to improve on it.